# List/Menu estático mostrando opção do banco

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de poder entender um problema que tenho aqui.
Criei um list/menu estático, mas preciso deixar marcado opção gravada no banco, quando tenho uma tabela que me possibilite o relacionamento faço legal, como nesse caso:

```
<?php  
    mysql_select_db($database_conCurriculo, $conCurriculo);
    $QueryEstado = "SELECT * FROM estado_civil";
    $EstadoCivil = mysql_query($QueryEstado, $conCurriculo) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row_EstadoCivil = mysql_fetch_assoc($EstadoCivil)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row_EstadoCivil["id"]."'"; 
        if ($estadocivil == $row_EstadoCivil["id"]) { 
            echo "selected";
        }
        echo ">".$row_EstadoCivil["estado"]."</option>\n";
    }
?>
```

No caso acima tenho a tabela *estado_civil* ai verifico se o `$estadocivil` é igual ao que está no banco e deixo a opção selecionada, mas no meu problema é que não tenho uma tabela que me possibilite essa interação.
Criei um List/Menu com as opções estáticas e gostaria de saber como marcar a opção que está no banco.

O que tenho é isso:

```
<select name="nivelingles" id="nivelingles">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
    <option value="B&aacute;sico">B&aacute;sico</option>
    <option value="Intermedi&aacute;rio">Intermedi&aacute;rio</option>
    <option value="Avan&ccedil;ado">Avan&ccedil;ado</option>
</select>
```

No banco tenho gravado no campo `nivel_ingles` a opção "Intermediário", será que alguém poderia me ajudar ou me dar alguma dica de como fazer?

Valeu e fiquem na paz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que algo assim deva funcionar:

```
<select name="nivelingles" id="nivelingles">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
    <option value="B&aacute;sico" 
        <?php if ($nivel_ingles == "Básico") {echo "selected";} ?> 
    >B&aacute;sico</option>

    <option value="Intermedi&aacute;rio"
        <?php if ($nivel_ingles == "Intermediário") {echo "selected";} ?>
    >Intermedi&aacute;rio</option>

    <option value="Avan&ccedil;ado"
        <?php if ($nivel_ingles == "Avançado") {echo "selected";} ?>
    >Avan&ccedil;ado</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Olá "rocmartins".
Muito obrigado pela ajuda, estava com problemas na acentuação,
agradeço a ajuda.